# Installing Gamelift, cmake openssl problem

Tags: cmake, command-prompt, prompt, unreal-engine5, amazon-gamelift

Hi i'm installing gamelift for unreal engine but for the moment i'm stuck in a prompt command (i'm using Windows 11 and visual studio 2022)

```
msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release
```

For the moment it giving me an error, Cmak don't found OPEN SSL

```
    Performing forcebuild step for 'aws-cpp-sdk-gamelift-server'
  Force build of aws-cpp-sdk-gamelift-server
  Performing configure step for 'aws-cpp-sdk-gamelift-server'
  loading initial cache file C:/Users/Saif/Downloads/GameLift-Cpp-ServerSDK-5.0.0/out/aws-cpp-sdk-gamelift-server-prefix/tmp/aws-cpp-sdk-gamelift-server-cache-Release.cmake
  CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
    system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:670 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
    CMakeLists.txt:53 (find_package)
```

Hope someone can help me !

Comment: did you try doing what the diagnostic message suggested that you do?

Comment: Hi yes i tried it and after a long search...openssl not installed i did and now it works with other errors. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The part of the error message you should take note of:

```
Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

As found in the comments, you needed to install OpenSSL.